# Bootstrap 4: HTML - Using a Div with the Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my project, I have implemented bootstrap in order to create a navbar. This works successfully, and the navbar is fully responsive.

When the screen reaches a certain size, the hamburger icon appears which allows users to select navbar options.

After a user presses the hamburger icon, I want a little box/div to appear directly below. I have performed a media query so that the box does not appear when the hamburger icon disappears.

However what I want to implement is that when the user rescales the window, I want the div box to move along with the hamburger icon.

Here is my **existing code**:

```
<nav style="height: 80px;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <img src="{% static 'myicon.png' %}" style="margin-left: -15px;" width="99px" height="91px" class="navbar-brand bIcon" alt="Image of scissors and comb">
   <div class="navbar-brand" style="width: 1px; left: 100px; bottom: 1px;  position: absolute; height: 77px; border: 1px solid #454545;"></div>
   <span class="navbar-brand" style="position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 125px; font-size: 26px; letter-spacing: 1px;" >Test</span>
   <button style="margin-top: -16px;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      // HERE IS THE DIV/BOX I AM TALKING ABOUT => 
      <div class="collapseBox" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid white;"></div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Does anybody know how to implement this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I did:

- your navigation has the class `navbar-expand-lg` which means that burger menu disappears on sizes lg and above... so we assigned the class `d-lg-none` to our div `collapseBox`
- you wanted this div directly under the burger menu, so we get `position:absolute` for this
- next, the burger menu has a margin of 16px to its right (due to margin on the `nav` element), so we move our div to the right by 16px;
- the height of the nav is 80px, so we move our div down by 80px also

**working snippet** below:

```css
.collapseBox {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right;
  right: 16px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav style="height: 80px;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <img src="{% static 'myicon.png' %}" style="margin-left: -15px;" width="99px" height="91px" class="navbar-brand bIcon" alt="Image of scissors and comb">
  <div class="navbar-brand" style="width: 1px; left: 100px; bottom: 1px;  position: absolute; height: 77px; border: 1px solid #454545;"></div>
  <span class="navbar-brand" style="position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 125px; font-size: 26px; letter-spacing: 1px;">Test</span>
  <button style="margin-top: -16px;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    // HERE IS THE DIV/BOX I AM TALKING ABOUT =>
    <div class="collapseBox d-lg-none"></div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```